# How to get incoming call number? [Android]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, user-permissions

I'm trying to get incoming call number with Android but it return null.

I add user permission inside manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
```

and using this class:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
    }
 },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

but doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note you need permission `READ_CALL_LOG` if you want to get `incomingNumber`, you can check documents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String))

> String: call phone number. If application does not have READ_CALL_LOG permission or carrier privileges (see TelephonyManager#hasCarrierPrivileges), an empty string will be passed as an argument.